# Return parent data with child document from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is is possible to return parent data with a search for child documents within an Elasticsearch query?

I have two document types, e.g. Book and Chapter, that are related as Parent/Child (not nested).

I want to run a search on the child document and return the child document, with some of the fields from the parent document. I'm trying to avoid executing a separate query on the parent.

**Update**

The only way possible I can find is to use the `has_child` query and then a series of aggregations to drill back to the children and apply the query/filter again. However, this seems overly complicated and inefficient.

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "chapter",
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "field": "value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
"name1": {
  "terms": {
    "size": 50,
    "field": "id"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "name2": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 50
      }
    },
    "name3": {
      "children": {
        "type": "type2"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docFilter": {
          "filter": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "_all": "value"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "docs": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 50
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. The documents returned for a `nested` query do include the fields in the "root" documents.

Comment: I've updated the original question with more info.

Comment: I am wondering if you found answer for this. I am looking for exactly same query.

Answer (score 3):

This can be now be done with ElasticSearch. Just use 'has_parent' in the search query:

```
'has_parent': {
    'parent_type': 'book',
    'query': {
        'match_all': {}
    },
    'inner_hits': {}
}
```

The results will appear in the inner_hits of the response.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible do a `has_child` query to return the parent docs with a `top hits` aggregation to return the child docs, but it is a bit cumbersome.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

The `Inner Hits` feature that is due to be released in 1.5.0 will do what you want.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-inner-hits.html

You could build the source from master and try it out.

Comment: That was my thoughts too. I've updated the question with my 'has_child' approach. Unfortunately I can't use 1.5 as it's not released and supported.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Tuffery say in his comment, currently, this can be achieve with Inner Hits, in Java you can understand it more easy with the next snippet of code.

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = this.transportClient.prepareSearch("your_index")
                .setTypes("your_type")
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(
                                null,
                                FilterBuilders.hasParentFilter(
                                        "parent_type_name",
                                        FilterBuilders.termFilter("foo", "foo"))
                                .innerHit(new QueryInnerHitBuilder()))
                )
                .execute().actionGet();

List<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (SearchHit searchHit : searchHits.getHits()) {

    YourObject yourObject = this.objectMapper.readValue(searchHit.getSourceAsString(), YourObject.class);
    yourObject.setYourParentObject(this.objectMapper.readValue(searchHit.getInnerHits().get("parent_type_name").getAt(0).getSourceAsString(), YourParentObject.class));

    list.add(yourObject);
}
```